# Trouble compiling .c and header files with gcc in Ubuntu WSL

Tags: c, multithreading, memory, segmentation-fault

I am trying to compile some c code with multithreading and for some reason I'm getting a segmentation fault in the Ubuntu WSL terminal when I try to run:

> gcc -o mashu concurrent_list.c concurrent_list.h

The files I am trying to run are the following:

concurrent_list.c:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "concurrent_list.h"

struct node {
  int value;
  node* next;
  pthread_mutex_t* lock;
  // add more fields
};

struct list {
  // add fields
  node* head;
  pthread_mutex_t* lock;
};

void print_node(node* node)
{
  // DO NOT DELETE
  if(node)
  {
    printf("%d ", node->value);
  }
}

list* create_list()
{
  // add code here
  list* l = malloc(sizeof(list));
  if(l == NULL){
    printf("malloc error");
  }
  l->head = NULL;
  l->head->next = NULL;
  if(pthread_mutex_init(l->lock, NULL) != 0){
     printf("mutex init failed\n");
  }
  if(pthread_mutex_init(l->head->lock, NULL) != 0){
    printf("mutex init failed\n");
  }
  return l;
}

void delete_list(list* list)
{
  // add code here
  pthread_mutex_lock(list->lock);
  node* head = list->head;
  node* next = head->next;
  while(next->next != NULL){
    free(head);
    next = next->next;
    head = next;
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(list->lock);
  free(list);
}

void insert_value(list* list, int value)
{
  // add code here

  // if the list is empty
  pthread_mutex_lock(list->lock);
  if(list->head == NULL){
    list->head->value = value;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(list->lock);
  }
  else{
    // init newnode
    node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(!newNode){
      printf("malloc failed\n");
    }
    newNode->value = value;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if(pthread_mutex_init(newNode->lock, NULL) != 0){
      printf("mutex init failed\n");
    }

    node* curr = list->head;
    // lock the list and the first node 
    pthread_mutex_lock(curr->lock);
    if(curr->next == NULL){ // first and only node at the start of a list
      if(curr->value > value){  // insert the newnode at the beggining
        list->head = newNode;
        newNode->next = curr;
      }else{
        curr->next = newNode;
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(list->lock);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(curr->lock);
      // finished the insert
    }
    else{
      node* prev = curr;
      curr = curr->next;
      pthread_mutex_unlock(list->lock);
      pthread_mutex_lock(curr->lock);
      while(curr->value < value && curr->next != NULL){
        pthread_mutex_unlock(prev->lock);
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        pthread_mutex_lock(curr->lock);
      }
      if(curr->next == NULL){
        curr->next = newNode;
      }else{
        prev->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = curr;
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(prev->lock);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(curr->lock);
    }
  }
}

void remove_value(list* list, int value)
{
  // add code here
  
  
  
}

void print_list(list* list)
{
  // add code here
  node* curr = list->head;
  pthread_mutex_lock(list->lock);
  if(curr != NULL){
    pthread_mutex_unlock(list->lock);
    while(curr != NULL){
      pthread_mutex_lock(curr->lock);
      print_node(curr);
      curr = curr->next;
      pthread_mutex_unlock(curr->lock);
    }
  }
  printf("\n"); // DO NOT DELETE
}

void count_list(list* list, int (*predicate)(int))
{
  int count = 0; // DO NOT DELETE

  // add code here

  printf("%d items were counted\n", count); // DO NOT DELETE
}

int main(){
  list* l = create_list();
  printf("1\n");
  insert_value(l,6);
  printf("2\n");
  insert_value(l,12);
  insert_value(l,3);
  insert_value(l,19);
  insert_value(l,8);
  printf("3\n");
  print_list(l);
  printf("4\n");
  delete_list(l);
}
```

concurrent_list.h:

```
typedef struct node node;
typedef struct list list;

list* create_list();
void delete_list(list* list);
void print_list(list* list);
void insert_value(list* list, int value);
void remove_value(list* list, int value);
void count_list(list* list, int (*predicate)(int));
```

The thrown error when compiling is:

> Segmentation fault

Am I accessing illegal memory, not compiling correctly or am I using mutex threads wrong?

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: In `create_list()` you are setting `l->head = NULL` but then try to access `l->head` on the next line: `l->head->next = NULL`. You really need to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: In your structs, you have: `pthread_mutex_t *lock;` but that is never inited to point to anything. So you have UB. Change to: `pthread_mutex_t lock;` Then, do: `pthread_mutex_init(&newNode->lock, NULL);` and similar elsewhere.

Comment: I you lock the list for every update why do also need to lock each node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`create_list()`:

1. `l->head = NULL` will segfault if `malloc` failed.  You probably want to `return NULL;` in addition to the print.
2. `l->head->next = NULL;` will always segfault as you set `l->head` to `NULL`
3. `pthread_mutex_init(l->head->lock, NULL)` will always segfault as `l->head` is `NULL`.

`insert_value()`:

4. `list->head->value = value;` will segfault if `list->head` is `NULL`.  You even ensure that it is with the if statement.

As you lock the list on modification (and you need to do that at least for the head changes) I eliminated the node lock.  Inlined `print_node()` in `print_list()` as the former required caller to take a lock which is risky.  Fixed `create_list()` per above.  Simplified `delete_list()`.  Fixed (per above) and simplified `insert_value()`.  Removed dead code `remove_value()`:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

typedef struct node node;
struct node {
    int value;
    node *next;
};
typedef struct list list;
struct list {
    node *head;
    pthread_mutex_t *lock;
};

list* create_list();
void delete_list(list* list);
list *insert_value(list* list, int value);
void print_list(list* list);

list* create_list() {
    list* l = malloc(sizeof(*l));
    if(!l) {
        printf("malloc error");
        return NULL;
    }
    l->head = NULL;
    if(pthread_mutex_init(l->lock, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("mutex init failed\n");
    }
    return l;
}

void delete_list(list *l) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(l->lock);
    while(l->head) {
        node *n = l->head;
        l->head = l->head->next;
        free(n);
    }
    free(l);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(l->lock);
}


list *insert_value(list *l, int value) {
    node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(!newNode){
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    newNode->value = value;

    // head
    pthread_mutex_lock(l->lock);
    if(!l->head || value < l->head->value){
        newNode->next = l->head;
        l->head = newNode;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(l->lock);
        return l;
    }
    // non-head
    node *n = l->head;
    for(; n->next && value >= n->next->value; n = n->next);
    newNode->next = n->next;
    n->next = newNode;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(l->lock);
    return l;
}

void print_list(list *l) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(l->lock);
    for(node *n = l->head; n; n = n->next) {
        printf("%d ", n->value);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(l->lock);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(){
    list* l = create_list();
    printf("1\n");
    insert_value(l, 6);
    printf("2\n");
    insert_value(l,12);
    insert_value(l,3);
    insert_value(l,19);
    insert_value(l,8);
    printf("3\n");
    print_list(l);
    printf("4\n");
    delete_list(l);
}
```

and the output is:

```
1
2
3
3 6 8 12 19 
4
```